# How to see if a sprite has touched a rectangle?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am creating a program using pygame and was wondering if there was a command which worked out if a sprite touched a rectangle. So I have a sprite moving around a maze, and at the end, there is a rectangle. The rectangle doesn't do anything, if the sprite touches it, they will win. I know that there are if sprite touches another sprite commands, but I don't want to create another sprite. The code for the rectangle is as follows:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, pink, [1005, 505, 19, 19])
```

Comment: @usr2564301 It doesn't matter what colour the rectangle is. (I shall change the question)

Comment: It's difficult to give you advice because we can't see your code. Please read the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add your code to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not having full access to your code, but I think you can use the [`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to do the collision check. This function test if two rectangles overlap.

> **colliderect()**
>   colliderect(Rect) -> bool
>
> Returns true if any portion of either rectangle overlap (except the
>   top+bottom or left+right edges).

Minimal example:

```
your_sprite.get_rect().colliderect(your_goal_rect)
```

Comment: This looks more like a workaround for this specific scenario, where the colored pixels are inside a rectangle.

Comment: That's the desired result, isn't it? Do I miss something?

Comment: It is, in this case, where the colored pixels are inside the rectangle. That's why the workaround works.

Comment: @DanielF: but it is a valid interpretation of OP's intentions. Based on the title, I was expecting having to test any stray pixel – which needs a lot more code to run efficiently (as I estimate a brute force method would not scale well).

Comment: The title is a bit misleading indeed. Once the OP clarifies it, we can update the title.

Comment: @usr2564301 If you google for the title because you're in the need for it, this answer won't help you, unless you have the same constraints as the OP. Yet I wouldn't downvote this answer, it's good to have it in this context.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python_programmes/pygame/james_bond_maze/main.py", line 358, in <module>
    player.get_rect().colliderect(pygame.draw.rect(screen, pink, [1005, 505, 19, 19]))
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'get_rect'

Comment: @AndrewBell you should probably first define the rect: `my_rect = pygame.Rect(1005, 505, 19, 19)` and then pass it to the `colliderect` method of the player's rect: `player.rect.colliderect(my_rect)`.